# Confusion with the Javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, date, email

I am using `simple-parser` from [mail-parser](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser) to parse some emails (in combination with [node-mbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mbox)). These are wonderful libs and I have it all working but I am having trouble with the JavaScript `Date` object.

According to the [`simple-parser` docs](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser) the date of a parsed email is a date object:

> date is a Date object for the Date: header

But for some reason I am not able to work with it as an object. I want to pull out the date.year, date.month, etc. If I log it, it appears to be an object – but I am not able to treat it as such: in example below `myDate.year` is reported as undefined.

Am I doing something wrong here? If I treat the mail.date as a string and try to create a new Date object, it still doesn't work correctly.

---

```
 console.log('mail', mail);
 var myDate = mail.date;
 console.log('myDate', myDate, typeof myDate);
 console.log('year', myDate.year)
```

---

**Console Output:**

[image]

Comment: Documentation of the Javascript `Date` object is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the javascript `Date` object, to get the year you can use the `getFullYear()` function - it's not stored as a property "year" on the object:

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear(); //2017
var month = date.getMonth(); //3 [starts w/ 0]
var day = date.getDate(); //6
```

Comment: Thanks... I feel like an idiot. Why did I think they were properties of the date object?

Comment: Haha no worries! Glad to help

Comment: @NoGrabbing—if written today, it would likely be a property with a getter. [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getfullyear) requires the value to be calculated every time (though likely implementations are optimised to not actually do that unless there is a change to system settings).